# Multiple image sprites vs one

Tags: image, performance, web, sprite

I currently have two image sprites on my website - one "general" sprite and another for navigation bar images. All of the images are used in some way or another on the front page (some get shown when the screen shrinks, using media queries).

Perhaps apart from organisational concerns is there any reason not to combine the two into a single file and eliminate a request along with its overhead?

Thanks.

Comment: This kinda answers my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6972758/multiple-images-vs-spritesheet